# Most occurring element in a list

Tags: python, list

Is there a way to output a list of the most occurring element from a list into a list or all of the most occurred elements if there is a tie?

I would like to solve this without importing any classes!

For example, [5,4,3] would output [5,4,3].

or

[5,4,4,5] would output [5,4]

I have tried, max(set(list), key=list.count) but does not really work for ties.

my work so far:

```
test = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
dict = {}

for elements in test:
    if elements in dict:
        dict[elements] += 1
    else:
        dict[elements] = 0
        dict[elements] += 1

print (dict)
```

Comment: Use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev yes, edited!

Comment: what is wrong with your second solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), find the maximum count and then keep those that have maximum count:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter([5, 4, 4, 5, 3])

max_count = max(counts.values())
result = [k for k, count in counts.items() if count == max_count]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[5, 4]
```

You could substitute the Counter by a simple dictionary:

```
data = [5, 4, 4, 5, 3]
counts = {}

for e in data:
    counts[e] = counts.get(e, 0) + 1

max_count = max(counts.values())
result = [k for k, count in counts.items() if count == max_count]

print(result)
```

Comment: this works but im looking for a way without imports. thanks!

Comment: @user145682 Updated the answer!